# How to parse complex nested JSON data in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm having kind of complex nested JSON in my dynamoDB, I want to extract this `Filter` object and its values. **For example,** if `Type` is `macBook` return the `Filter` object and its value `PRO` and `AIR`. Please find my code below and JSON input - I'm struggling to parse these value in NodeJS - could someone please help me - how to get the Filter Object?

**JSON**

```
{
  "ProductType": {
    "S": "Apple"
  },
  "Type": {
    "M": {
      "iPhone": {
        "M": {
          "Filter": {
            "M": {
              "model": {
                "SS": [
                  "X", "XS"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "macBook": {
        "M": {
          "Filter": {
            "M": {
              "model": {
                "SS": [
                  "PRO", "AIR"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**product.js**

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
  });

const getModel = function (productType) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var params = {
            Key: {
                "ProductType": {
                    S: productType
                }
            },
            TableName: 'product'
        };
        dynamodb.getItem(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) reject(err, err.stack);
            else {
                console.log("data: " + Object.keys(data));
                let product = data.Item.ProductType.S;
                let filterModel = data.Item.Type.M
                console.log(filterModel);

                
                
            }

        });
    });
}

getModel('Apple')
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Object.values` to get the values of `iPhone` and `macbook` objects, then inside you can use `flatMap` to find the `Filter` whose has `PRO", "AIR"` properties.

```js
const data ={
  "ProductType": {
    "S": "Apple"
  },
  "Type": {
    "M": {
      "iPhone": {
        "M": {
          "Filter": {
            "M": {
              "model": {
                "SS": [
                  "X", "XS"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "macBook": {
        "M": {
          "Filter": {
            "M": {
              "model": {
                "SS": [
                  "PRO", "AIR"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


const result = Object.values(data.Type.M).flatMap((item) => {
  const SS = item.M.Filter.M.model.SS
  return SS.includes('PRO') && SS.includes('AIR') ? [{ Filter: item.M.Filter.M }] : []
}, [])

console.log(result)
```